# module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'PhantomJS'

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am running PhantomJS by

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='E:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe')
```

but the program fails, saying

> AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'PhantomJS'.

OS is Windows 10. 
My python version is 3.6, selenium version is 3.8.0, and the phantomjs version is 2.1.1. All of them is newest.

Thanks if anyone could offer a hand!

Following is the screenshot of [selenium version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBJs9.png).

Comment: Do you have a local module/file named `selenium.py` by any chance?

Comment: `PhantomJS` support is being deprecated, but you should still (in 3.8.0) be able to do `webdriver.PhantomJS(...)` where `webdriver` is imported this way: `from selenium import webdriver`.

Comment: Yes, it is just what i code.

Answer (score 10):

I drew attention to this question while I was looking for an answer to it in google. It took me quite a lot of work to find the answer to it, so in order to save some work for others, and although a lot of time has passed since this question, I advise you not to use PhantomJS at this moment. On the official site of Selenium https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_browser_drivers/ you can read the quote: "PhantomJS is a headless browser based on Webkit, albeit a version much older than that used by Google Chrome or Safari. Whilst historically a popular choice, it would now be wise to avoid PhantomJS. The project has been unmaintained since the 5th of August 2017, so whilst the web will continue to change, PhantomJS will not be updated. This was after Google announced the ability to run Chrome headlessly, something also now offered by Mozilla’s Firefox.". I changed to Mozilla’s Firefox (I use it headlessly).

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not in code or anything is that the Selenium community stopped supporting PhantomJS in the new version, so every time you try to pull the PhatomJs lib it doesn't exist.
In the documentation it says that they currently support
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html

Answer (score 4):

The native support for Opera and PhantomJS is removed in Selenium 4, as their WebDriver implementations are no longer under development. The Opera browser is based on Chromium, and users looking to test their implementation on Opera can opt for testing on the Chrome browser.

Install Older Version:

```bash
pip uninstall selenium 
pip install -U selenium==3.3.0
```

ref : [Full Explanation Link](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/what-is-deprecated-in-selenium4/#:%7E:text=The%20native%20support%20for%20Opera,testing%20on%20the%20Chrome%20browser.)

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the single quotes `(\)` in the path you should pass the raw **`(r)`** switch along as follows :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'E:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe')
```

---

### Update :

If the error still exists check the following through **`Command Prompt`** :

- Check **`Selenium`** version :

  ```
  >pip show -V selenium
  ```

  You must see an output like :

  ```
  Name: selenium
  Version: 3.8.0
  Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
  Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
  Author: UNKNOWN
  Author-email: UNKNOWN
  License: Apache 2.0
  Location: c:\python\lib\site-packages
  Requires:
  ```
- Check all the **`packages`** installed :

  ```
  >pip freeze
  ```

  You must see an output like :

  ```
  Selenium==3.8.0
  ```

If the following commands **Fails** which means **`Selenium`** was not properly installed. So you have to do :

```
>pip install -U selenium
```

As an alternative you can **uninstall** **`Selenium`** and **install** again as follows :

```
>pip uninstall selenium
>pip install -U selenium
```

Here is the complete [**`Installation Instructions`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) for your reference.

Comment: The advice is good, but I am failing to understand how it relates to the OP's error..

Comment: @alecxe Thanks. That is what I suspect at the first go. But have added further steps. Please let me know if the `Answer` looks good.

Comment: Thanks. But I've checked as you wrote and the result has been added to the end of the question. It seems the problem is not related to that.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem.
The reason is that I use pycharm as IDE. And I create the project using **virtual environment**. That's why I cannot use the libraries I installed.

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: you should be use comments